# I can't see the console in my RStudio. I can do nothing with it actually. What can be the problem?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm a beginner user who downloaded the programmes for my Statistics class. But I cannot do anything with my RStudio. Once I open it, it stucks with a base screen as shown image. What is wrong with it? This is the first time running it. Besides, I deleted both R and RStudio and tried it again but it didn't help. RGui itself works fine but Rstudio does not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After this white screen, it has to give you the home console. Make sure you run the R Studio as an Administrator. Download the latest version ( https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/windows/RStudio-1.2.5042.exe )